# Tomcat started but application is not running

Tags: spring, tomcat, server

I created a spring application and deployed it in tomcat server (Tomcat v5.5 Server). I checked in tomcat manager and found my application is listed.But while i try to run my application,i am getting a page showing

**This program cannot display the webpage

Most likely causes:
You are not connected to the Internet. 
The website is encountering problems. 
There might be a typing error in the address.

What you can try: 
     Check your Internet connection. Try visiting another website to make sure you are connected.

Retype the address.**

I don't know where i am missing out.Please help me in sorting out this issue.

My web.xml file as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
     <context-param>
    <description>Log4j configuration file used by spring to initialize logging</description>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:pricingLog4j.properties</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <description>By default myfaces serializes the current view and saves it in session after view is rendered.
        In Pricing UI, values on the Page tags are bound to UIComponents on backing bean using "binding" attribute. Most of the components are created
        in the backing bean. When myfces serializes, it serializes the wrapped object under UIComponents, i.e HtmlDataTabl's value attribute, which are in Pricing UI case
        business objects which have a big graphs attached to it and you start getting "serialization" error

        Keep this pram-value to false to avoid serialization.</description>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <description>Comma separated list of URIs of (additional) faces config
            files. (e.g. /WEB-INF/my-config.xml) See JSF 1.0 PRD2,
            10.3.2. 
            DONOT ADD DEFAULT faces-config.xml HERE. IT IS AUTOMATICALLY LOADED BY FACES. IF GIVEN HERE, IT WILL BE LOADED TWICE</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-navigation.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
  <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/taglib/tomahawk-taglib.xml;
            /WEB-INF/taglib/tomahawk-sandbox-taglib.xml;
            /WEB-INF/taglib/jcp-pricing-ui-taglib.xml;
            /WEB-INF/taglib/acegijsf-taglib.xml
  </param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
            classpath:/config/pricingEngineContext-caching.xml
            classpath:/config/pricingEngineContext-messaging.xml
            classpath:/config/pricingEngineContext-service.xml
            classpath:/config/pricingEngineContext.xml
            classpath:/config/pricingWebApplicationContext.xml
            classpath:/config/securityContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <description>State saving method: "client" or "server" (= default) See
            JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>server</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <description>This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be
            allowed in the rendered HTML output. If javascript is
            allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code that
            submits the corresponding form. If javascript is not
            allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters will be
            added as url parameters. Default: "true"</description>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <description>If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is
            "human readable". i.e. additional line separators and
            whitespace will be written, that do not influence the HTML
            code. Default: "true"</description>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <description>If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able
            to restore the former vertical scroll on every request.
            Convenient feature if you have pages with long lists and you
            do not want the browser page to always jump to the top if
            you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same
            page. Default: "false"</description>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <!-- Special Debug Output for Development -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
  <param-value>2</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param> 
  <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.SKIN</param-name> 
  <param-value>DEFAULT</param-value> 
 </context-param> 
 <filter>
  <filter-name>Acegi Channel Processing Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
   <param-value>org.acegisecurity.securechannel.ChannelProcessingFilter</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter>
  <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
   <param-value>org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>
 <!-- Spring Open Session In View Pattern filter -->
 <filter>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
   <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>
 <!-- Extensions Filter -->
 <filter>
  <description>Set the size limit for uploaded files. Format: 10 - 10 bytes
            10k - 10 KB 10m - 10 MB 1g - 1 GB</description>
  <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
   <param-value>100m</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <description>Set the threshold size - files below this limit are
                stored in memory, files above this limit are stored on
                disk.

                Format: 10 - 10 bytes 10k - 10 KB 10m - 10 MB 1g - 1 GB</description>
   <param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
   <param-value>100k</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <description>Set the path where the intermediary files will be
                stored.</description>
   <param-name>uploadRepositoryPath</param-name>
   <param-value>/tmp</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter>
  <filter-name>orchestraFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.orchestra.conversation.jsf.filter.OrchestraServletFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter>
  <filter-name>promotionFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.jcpenney.web.servlet.PromotionFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter> 
  <display-name>Ajax4jsf Filter</display-name> 
  <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name> 
  <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class> 
 </filter> 
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Acegi Channel Processing Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>orchestraFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <!-- Spring/Hibernate filter mappings -->
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.remoting</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <!-- Filter Mappings necessary to run myfaces -->
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>promotionFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name> 
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
<!-- Myfaces JSF Listener, that does all the startup work (configuration, init). -->
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.orchestra.conversation.servlet.ConversationManagerSessionListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>com.jcpenney.pricing.web.listeners.SessionLoggingListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>com.jcpenney.pricing.audit.LogoutLogger</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <!-- This servlet is needed to workaround a websphere bug (http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMAHAWK-663)
    Another workaround is on Websphere set com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility=true as container 
    property, but that is one more step for server configuration team
 -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Tomahawk-663 Websphere Workaround Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.jcpenney.web.Tomahawk663Servlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet> 
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>debug</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet> 
 <!-- Mapping for MyFaces components -->
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <!-- This mapping is needed to back the MyFaces Extention Filter to workaround a websphere bug -->
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Tomahawk-663 Websphere Workaround Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- pricingUi Monitoring Simple Spring Servlet-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>pricingUi-monitoring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pricingUi-monitoring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ping</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pricingUi-monitoring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/ping</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 


    <!-- Spring Message Dispatcher Servlet for WebServices Call -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>pricingEngine</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:config/pricingEngineContext-webservice.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sale-price-upload</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sale-price-upload</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/salePriceFileUpload</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pricingEngine</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pricingEngine</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.wsdl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

 <!-- Session Configuration -->
 <session-config>
  <!-- the time until the session expires in min (60min)-->
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
 <!-- Welcome files -->
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
 </login-config>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Look in your tomcat log file, to find out if you get any exception at deployment.

Comment: can you share more like your web.xml? and tomcat logs

Comment: Does tomcat default application work? Where your server and your browser are running? What is the URL that you are using to access yoru application?

Comment: I added my web.xml file.Could anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: In log files i didnt found any exceptions.Both my server and browser are running in my local machine only.I am accessing my application using localhost link.

Comment: From the error message it appears that you hit wrong url, as it is message from browser not Tomcat. (or Tomcat was not started)

Comment: how to find correct url.where it will be configured.

Comment: Check the port configuration too, localhost:8080 is the standard. After this you have to type your application name like localhost:8080/myApplication But if you don't define the name explicitly it is the name of the deployed file. For example if you deployed myApplication-1-0-0.war then you have to type localhost:8080/myApplication-1-0-0 to access your application.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the exact log messages that is generated for this Error here in the question. Not enough information.

It is also not mentioned how you are building your application and whether the application build is successful or not. I assuming the build is successful.

For a workaround suggestion, if you are using `pom.xml` in your application and maven to build, can you please check the `<source>` and `<target>` of your application?

```
<source>1.8</source> 
<target>1.8</target>
```

If the java version that is mentioned in your pom is mis-matched with your system's java version, the error may appear. That is, your server may startup but your application maynot.

Also you can check your system's java version by using below commands like:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

Both the versions should be matched. If you see any difference, change the necessary and rebuild your application and restart the server.